# Image added in email template using velocity template doesnt show in gmail

Tags: java, spring-mvc, velocity

I am using velocity template to to send email from my spring Web App. In velocity template i added a pram to get company logo.This pram is basically a url of my Web App . While i hit this url from my browser its working fine and giving the image as well but while i open the email sent to a gmail account it shows broken image over there. I try to figure it out and found that google replaced my url with its own url which contain my url also.See the difference below.
Showing in gmail

```
<img src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/_IFpFiP--5tMScB3I2TKKXI0V3gk5RcYzhFxNh-hzgab32qHyZZ1cFiU-mBigpvk8eO1dniAoNZebw15PIfFqquf_28X8XvbiVu2eaB4jYNcsb-mStpNlzfPr7i-_8OOaa7Xa0HxhXkVZHI=s0-d-e1-ft#https://myurl/downloadCompanyLogo?companyId=3328" style="height:30px;margin-bottom:0" alt="" class="CToWUd">
```

Actule Url

```
https://myurl/downloadCompanyLogo?companyId=3328
```

If i replace the google provided url with my url it showing everything fine. It tried to access the google provided url externally but it shows something went wrong.

Can some tell me whats going on? My url is working fine but not in gmail ??

Answer (score 0):

After long discussions and R&D,I found the solutions of this problem . Basically this was happing as Google cached the images attached to any email and replace its actual URL with Google's cached images URL, That was the problem because in our case image server was firewall protracted and Google was not whit-listed over there so Google was not able to cache the image from the URL provided in email but it replace the URL thats why it was showing breaking image in email. You can also check this if you will foreword the same email to other email client this problem might not come if the URL will not be replaced.